# A bit stuck building a filter functionality

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, if-statement

Im currently building a filter that gets executed upon click on react.

The initial value of the filter in the state is as follow:

```
    state = {
        checkBoxes: [],
        filter: { breedFor: [], temperaments: [], size: [] },
    };
```

I have a bunch of boxes that update the filter upon change here the logic below:

```
    onChangeCheckboxHandler = (event) => {
        // Creates the checkboxes for the State
        const copyOfCheckBoxes = this.state.checkBoxes;
        checkBoxesStateCreator(copyOfCheckBoxes, event);

        // MANAGES THE FILTER FOR THE STATE DEPENDING ON INPUT CHANGES
        const copyOfFilter = this.state.filter;
        const { breedFor, temperaments, size } = copyOfFilter;
        manageFiltersChanges(breedFor, temperaments, size, event);

        this.setState({
            checkBoxes: copyOfCheckBoxes,
            filter: { ...copyOfFilter },
        });
    };
```

Now, I have a sample of the data coming from an api that contains data about the items on the UI. Each of the object elements contains three different properties that I want to filter depending on the filters that the user selects.

This does not have to be an exact match, but that at least have one of the characteristics from the filter.

See below:

```
const dogsCharacteristicsData = [
    {
        id: 1,
        bredFor: ['hunting'],
        temperaments: [
            'stubborn',
            'curious,',
            'playful,',
            'adventurous,',
            'active,',
            'fun-loving',
        ],
        size: 'small',
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        bredFor: ['coursing', 'hunting'],
        temperaments: ['aloof', 'clownish,', 'dignified,', 'independent,', 'happy'],
        size: 'large',
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        bredFor: [],
        temperaments: ['wild', 'hardworking,', 'dutiful'],
        size: 'large',
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        bredFor: ['hunting'],
        temperaments: [
            'outgoing',
            'friendly,',
            'alert,',
            'confident,',
            'intelligent,',
            'courageous',
        ],
        size: 'medium',
    },
    {
        id: 5,
        bredFor: ['guarding'],
        temperaments: ['loyal', 'independent,', 'intelligent,', 'brave'],
        size: 'large',
    },
    {
        id: 6,
        bredFor: ['hunting'],
        temperaments: [
            'docile',
            'alert,',
            'responsive,',
            'dignified,',
            'composed,',
            'friendly,',
            'receptive,',
            'faithful,',
            'courageous',
        ],
        size: 'large',
    },
    {
        id: 7,
        bredFor: ['guarding'],
        temperaments: [
            'loving',
            'protective,',
            'trainable,',
            'dutiful,',
            'responsible',
        ],
        size: 'medium',
    },
    {
        id: 8,
        bredFor: ['hauling', 'pulling'],
        temperaments: [
            'friendly',
            'affectionate,',
            'devoted,',
            'loyal,',
            'dignified,',
            'playful',
        ],
        size: 'large',
    },
    {
        id: 9,
        bredFor: [],
        temperaments: [
            'friendly',
            'affectionate,',
            'devoted,',
            'loyal,',
            'dignified,',
            'playful',
        ],
        size: 'large',
    },
    {
        id: 11,
        bredFor: [],
        temperaments: [
            'strong',
            'willed',
            'stubborn,',
            'friendly,',
            'clownish,',
            'affectionate,',
            'loyal,',
            'obedient,',
            'intelligent,',
            'courageous',
        ],
        size: 'small',
    },
    {
        id: 12,
        bredFor: [],
        temperaments: [
            'friendly',
            'alert,',
            'reserved,',
            'intelligent,',
            'protective',
        ],
        size: 'medium',
    },
    {
        id: 13,
        bredFor: [],
        temperaments: [
            'friendly',
            'alert,',
            'reserved,',
            'intelligent,',
            'protective',
        ],
        size: 'small',
    },
    {
        id: 14,
        bredFor: ['hunting'],
        temperaments: [
            'kind',
            'sweet-tempered,',
            'loyal,',
            'independent,',
            'intelligent,',
            'loving',
        ],
        size: 'large',
    },
    {
        id: 15,
        bredFor: ['fighting'],
        temperaments: [
            'strong',
            'willed',
            'stubborn,',
            'friendly,',
            'clownish,',
            'affectionate,',
            'loyal,',
            'obedient,',
            'intelligent,',
            'courageous',
        ],
        size: 'medium',
    },
    {
        id: 17,
        bredFor: ['flushing', 'retrieving'],
        temperaments: [
            'friendly',
            'energetic,',
            'obedient,',
            'intelligent,',
            'protective,',
            'trainable',
        ],
        size: 'medium',
    },
];
```

I'm currently trying to design the logic and see if I can get it to work even though the code is long and inefficient. At the moment I wrote the following long code:

```
    searchRequestHandler = () => {
        const filterCopy = this.state.filter;
        const copyOfResults = this.state.results;
        const dogsCharacteristicsData = dataFromServerModelerUponSearch(
            this.props.dogs
        );
        const results = [];
        let resultsBredFor;
        let resultsTemperament;
        let resultsSize;

        if (
            filterCopy.breedFor.length !== 0 &&
            filterCopy.temperaments.length !== 0 &&
            filterCopy.size.length !== 0
        ) {
            console.log('all have something');
            resultsBredFor = dogsCharacteristicsData.filter((dog) => {
                return dog.bredFor.some((bredCharacteristic) =>
                    filterCopy.breedFor.includes(bredCharacteristic)
                );
            });

            resultsTemperament = dogsCharacteristicsData.filter((dog) => {
                return dog.temperaments.some((bredCharacteristic) =>
                    filterCopy.temperaments.includes(bredCharacteristic)
                );
            });

            resultsSize = dogsCharacteristicsData.filter((dog) =>
                filterCopy.size.includes(dog.size)
            );
        }

        if (
            filterCopy.breedFor.length !== 0 &&
            filterCopy.temperaments.length !== 0 &&
            filterCopy.size.length === 0
        ) {
            console.log('breedFor and Temperaments have something');

            resultsBredFor = dogsCharacteristicsData.filter((dog) => {
                return dog.bredFor.some((bredCharacteristic) =>
                    filterCopy.breedFor.includes(bredCharacteristic)
                );
            });

            resultsTemperament = dogsCharacteristicsData.filter((dog) => {
                return dog.temperaments.some((bredCharacteristic) =>
                    filterCopy.temperaments.includes(bredCharacteristic)
                );
            });
        }

        if (
            filterCopy.breedFor.length !== 0 &&
            filterCopy.temperaments.length === 0 &&
            filterCopy.size.length !== 0
        ) {
            console.log('breedFor and size have something');
            resultsBredFor = dogsCharacteristicsData.filter((dog) => {
                return dog.bredFor.some((bredCharacteristic) =>
                    filterCopy.breedFor.includes(bredCharacteristic)
                );
            });

            resultsSize = dogsCharacteristicsData.filter((dog) =>
                filterCopy.size.includes(dog.size)
            );
        }

        if (
            filterCopy.breedFor.length !== 0 &&
            filterCopy.temperaments.length === 0 &&
            filterCopy.size.length === 0
        ) {
            console.log('breedFor have something');
            resultsBredFor = dogsCharacteristicsData.filter((dog) => {
                return dog.bredFor.some((bredCharacteristic) =>
                    filterCopy.breedFor.includes(bredCharacteristic)
                );
            });
        }

        if (
            filterCopy.breedFor.length === 0 &&
            filterCopy.temperaments.length !== 0 &&
            filterCopy.size.length !== 0
        ) {
            console.log('size and Temperaments have something');

            resultsTemperament = dogsCharacteristicsData.filter((dog) => {
                return dog.temperaments.some((bredCharacteristic) =>
                    filterCopy.temperaments.includes(bredCharacteristic)
                );
            });

            resultsSize = dogsCharacteristicsData.filter((dog) =>
                filterCopy.size.includes(dog.size)
            );
        }

        if (
            filterCopy.breedFor.length === 0 &&
            filterCopy.temperaments.length !== 0 &&
            filterCopy.size.length === 0
        ) {
            console.log('Temperaments have something');
            resultsTemperament = dogsCharacteristicsData.filter((dog) => {
                return dog.temperaments.some((bredCharacteristic) =>
                    filterCopy.temperaments.includes(bredCharacteristic)
                );
            });
        }

        if (
            filterCopy.breedFor.length === 0 &&
            filterCopy.temperaments.length === 0 &&
            filterCopy.size.length !== 0
        ) {
            console.log('size have something');
            console.log(filterCopy.size);
            resultsSize = dogsCharacteristicsData.filter((dog) =>
                filterCopy.size.includes(dog.size)
            );
        }

        console.log(resultsBredFor, resultsTemperament, resultsSize);
```

The console.log above shows that the conditions, filters are working but then I don't know how I can aggregate the data together. I tried:

```
const results = [].contact(resultsBredFor, resultsTemperament, resultsSize)
```

but this does not work because, in size for example, it keeps showing small, medium or large and does not prioritise. Even filtering the duplicates does not work either.

Should I condition the size as well? so if the size is specified it only shows those items (dogs)?

Comment: Why don't you filter in the backend? Please clarify a bit your final intention

Comment: I'm actually requesting this from a open api so I cant do this. My intention is to display those items that have the characteristics chosen by the user, but at the moment I can't figure out the logic

Comment: What do you mean by aggregating? Is it a table? If so, you can use a third party library in order to filter, in which case you will only have to implement the filtering function\property.

Comment: Basically, at the moment the results are in different arrays resultsBredFor, resultsTemperament, resultsSize. I want to merge them together so I have one list with the results. So I can then use this list to update the UI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you have an array of `dogsCharacteristicsData`.
In order to filter it by a filter, define a consistent filtering format, like you've done: say `filter: { breedFor: [], temperaments: [], size: [] }`.

Then in order to filter you can do something like:

```
function filterDogs(dogs, filter) {
    return dogs.filter(dog => filter.breedFor.includes(dog.bredFor) && filter.temperaments.includes(dog.temperaments) && filter.size.includes(dog.size)); 
}
```

Note that the filtering here assumes that your filtering is a contains filtering.

EDIT

`dog.bredFor` and `dog.temperaments` are arrays, so we need to treat them carefully.
Introduce a new intersection function:

```
function intersectionOfArrays(arr1, arr2) {
    return arr1.filter((element) => arr2.includes(element));
}
```

and then use it:

```
function filterDogs(dogs, filter) {
    return dogs.filter(dog => intersectionOfArrays(filter.breedFor, dog.bredFor) && intersectionOfArrays(filter.temperaments, dog.temperaments) && filter.size.includes(dog.size)); 
}
```

Comment: it returns an empty array unfortunately.

Comment: I've edited my answer to reflect the usage of intersection and includes

Comment: If this answer helped you, please upvote and accept it :)

Comment: I did, it was useful!

Comment: So remember to also upvote with the up arrow :)